# Boolean stream output representation in C++

Tags: c++, boolean, iostream

I have c++ code

```
int main()
{
   int a = 5, b=5;
   bool c;
   c = a == b;
   cout << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

> Output is 1

anyone please explain me how come output is 1 and why it is not true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because that's how `std::ostream::operator<<` formats `bool` values by default. It outputs a `1` for `true`, and a `0` for `false`. If you want to print the text `"true"` or `"false"`, you can use the `boolalpha` io manipulator:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << c;
```

Answer (score 7):

It's the default `stream` behaviour, but you can ask for textual representation using [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) as follows:

```
#include <iomanip>

...

cout << std::boolalpha << c << endl;
```

See [docs and examples here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

The reason it defaults to displaying `0` when `false` and `1` when `true` is largely historical - for the longest time C didn't have a dedicated `bool` type, and so the results of boolean operations like comparisons were encoded in integers.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is dependent on the flags of the output stream. The [std::ostream::operator<<(bool)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) function invokes [::std::ostream::num_put()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) whose behavior is dependent on the [boolalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) flag; if not set, the function performs a conversion to integer, first, before displaying the value.

You can change the behavior like this:

```
int main() {
  int a = 5, b=5;
  bool c;
  c = a == b;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << c << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note the crucial addition of `<< std::boolalpha` above. See also: [boolalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I will gladly explain!

First, let's look at your code:

**Your Code**

```
int main()
{
   int a = 5, b=5;
   bool c;
   c = a == b;
   cout << c << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Your first line states: `int a = 5, b = 5;` <-- This sets a variable

Your second line states: `bool c;` <-- basically sets this to a placeholder for a boolean variable

Your third line states: `bool = 5 == 5;` which is basically saying the c placeholder is now equal to `true`

Then when you print c here: `cout << c << endl;` you are basically saying, print the integer value of the boolean placeholder or print c which equals to true which equals to 1. Does that make sense?

**Reminder: In programming 0 = false and 1 = true. Hence binary the 1 and 0s really mean true or false, AKA on or off.**

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::boolalpha << c << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << (c ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

In C Comparision operator (==) always returns integer value.
i.e. if condition is correct it returns 1 otherwise it returns 0;
Hence answer is 1.

Comment: No, in C++, the operators with a boolean result return the proper `bool` type.